# Facebook Registration login display and routing issue on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Basically I am using a iframe for Facebook Registration

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/registration?
         client_id=<my_app_id>&
         redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/&
         fields=name,gender,email"
    scrolling="auto"
    frameborder="no"
    style="border:none"
    allowTransparency="true"
    width="100%"
    height="330">
</iframe>
```

The first problem is the fields gender and email are not showing, only the name is displayed

The second problem is when I click register, it routes to

```
/%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fields=name,gender,email
```

and I don't know why. Was expecting it to route to localhost as per indicated in the redirect_uri field.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The %20's appearing in your redirect are html-encoded spaces.

They're appearing because of the newlines and indentation in your iframe's SRC.

Try removing the newlines, and the redirect should work.

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/registration?client_id=<my_app_id>&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/&fields=name,gender,email" scrolling="auto" frameborder="no" style="border:none" allowTransparency="true" width="100%" height="330">
</iframe>
```